# Splitting and joining string with different line separators in Groovy

Tags: string, groovy

I have a string with multiple lines as content. These lines are seperated by either \n or \r\n. I need to change the content of each line without touching the separators.

Example:

input is: `aaaaaa \n bbbbbb \r\n cccccc \n ddddd \n eeee \r\n fffff`

output should be: `aaa11aaa \n bb22bb \r\n cc33cccc \n dd44ddd \n e55eee \r\n ffff66f`

Therefore splitting or tokenizing the input string is not possible as the information if it is \r\n or \n is lost and cannot be recovered when joining the tokens after changing them.

Instead of analyzing and changing the lines of the input string manually, is there a good groovy method I am missing that already does that for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to do it in two steps:

```
def input = 'aaaaaa \n bbbbbb \r\n cccccc \n ddddd \n eeee \r\n fffff'
def result = input.split('\r\n').collect {
    it.split('\n').collect { doYourReplaceLogic(it) }.join('\n')
}.join('\r\n')
```